# Cannot load symbols created with Ngen for Native Image DLLs

Tags: debugging, pdb-files, native-code, ngen

I am investigating a crashing program but cannot load symbols for native image DLLs in Visual Studio 2013. The application is 32-bit and uses .NET 4.0.30319. I confirmed this by checking what version of clr.dll is loaded into process from the modules window. Also from the modules window, I checked where mscorlib.ni.dll was loaded from:

```
clr.dll C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
mscorlib.ni.dll C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\ce5f61c5754789df97be8dc991c47d07\mscorlib.ni.dll
```

I was able to successfully generate the PDB for mscorlib.ni.dll:

[image: Ngen mscorlib.ni.dll output]

but when I try to load it into VS 2013 by right clicking on the stack frame for mscorlib.ni.dll and selecting Load Symbols, I get a messaged that says "A matching symbol file was not found in this folder."

I have looked through:

[Creating Ngen Pdbs for Profiling Reports/](http://creating-ngen-pdbs-for-profiling-reports) 
And followed the simple instructions for generating the PDB because I just want to see function calls at this point,

[Get the right .net native symols for Windbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32405305/get-the-right-net-native-symols-for-windbg/32409960#32409960)

[How to get the PDB file for mscorlib.ni.lib (.Net Framework 3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775844/how-to-get-the-pdb-file-for-mscorlib-ni-lib-net-framework-3-5)

It looks like the most common source of error is choosing the correct bitness. I know from the modules tab that I am loading the 32-bit variant of mscorlib.ni.dll and again from my screenshot, you can see that I am using the same version of the the .NET framework and the 32-bit version of Ngen.exe. I tried this for WindowsBase.ni.dll and saw the same behavior where I was successfully able to generate the PDB but could not load it.

I have the debugger enabled to Just-in-time debug Managed and Native code.

Questions:

1. Am I using the wrong version of ngen.exe on to create this PDB?
2. What does Visual Studio check when it tries to load a PDB?
3. Is there some other setting I need to enable in VS to debug this type of code?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you generated the PDB file, so provided the PDB is at your symbol path, you should be able to load it into windbg with [`.reload /f`](https://www.technlg.net/windows/symbol-server-path-windbg-debugging/).