Debugging application freeze (infinite loop) using dump
Is it possible to debug an infinite loop in a .NET application by creating a dump file and then attempting opening in Visual Studio?
Consider the following code:
while (fileContents.Length < charNum + 1)
{
    fileContents = File.ReadAllText(_filePath);
}

So I've made it so that the file it's trying to read contains only 5 characters, meaning it will get stuck in this loop. And as predicted, my application freezes.
So I use Task Manager to create a dump of the program, bring that to my dev computer, and open in Visual Studio, where I also have the exe, pdb and source code.
But when I try to debug I get:

mscrolib.ni.pdb not loaded
mscorlib.ni.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module

Apparently I can't get this pdb because it's a native image created by ngen.exe. TBH I'm not too concerned about it though (I can see File.ReadAllText in the disassembly so I'm assuming that's why it's stopped there), I just want to see where it's stopped in my own code and debug that.
Is there any way I can do this? I've tried looking at the call stack but all I get there is:

[External Code]
mscorlib.ni.dll![Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, native debugger attempting to walk managed call stack]   Unknown

Viewing Threads gives me 7 threads and this is the "Main Thread" - the rest (Worker Threads) are ntdll.dll, clr.dll and combase.dll - none with useful information so I feel I'm already looking at the correct thread.
Edit
So I opened the "Modules" window in the debugger and saw that every module had a Symbol Status = 'Symbols Loaded' except for my application and mscorlib.ni.dll! Now when I try to load the symbols for my application, I browse to and open the the pdb file from the original build, and I get an error saying:

A matching symbol file was not found in this folder.

But this is the symbol file from this .exe!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775844/how-to-get-the-pdb-file-for-mscorlib-ni-lib-net-framework-3-5

I used an infinite loop project similar to yours and generated a dump. When debugging, I was able to track the cause code normally, and the same situation as yours did not occur:

When debugging, I opened the module window and the status of mscorlib.ni.dll was Native debugger skipped loading symbols for managed module:

Please check whether the Enable Just My Code option is enabled in Tools > Options > Debugging > General, and whether the Microsoft Symbol Servers option is checked in Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols.
Related posts can be referenced: post1, post2.

Thanks for the response - Just thinking though, my project was built in Release mode - Possibly yours was built in Debug mode (judging by your screenshot). Could that possibly make the difference?

After I changed the mode to release, the debugging results were not affected at all, everything was normal, just like the pictures I uploaded above.

Thanks... Forgot to mention - those two options were indeed already enabled. But in the module window does it show your code as having Symbols Loaded or do you have that "Native debugger skipped loading symbols" as I have?

"After I changed the mode to release, the debugging results were not affected" - I wonder has it anything to do with me using 3 different devices - one to build, another to run, and a third to debug.

The status of mscorlib.ni.dll does show "Native debugger skipped loading symbols", but it does not affect the debugging results. In addition, I wonder why you use three devices, different devices may also be affected by some settings.

but what about the status of your own project / module? I'm using 3 devices to simulate real life conditions - i.e. my development machine, a build server and then the user's computer.

Regarding the status of my project/module you mentioned: the dump generated by my project can be debugged normally, and the module is just as shown in the picture in my answer above.
